# Rails sending parameters with array of id vs array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post

If I have a "Bill" entity, I might create that bill instance via REST API by assigning the food ordered to the bill when I go to create a new bill.

i.e. I might make a POST request to www.server.com/api/bills with following parameters:

```
{
    cost: 30.0,
    foods: [23, 1, 14]
}
```

Is it better to send an array of ids or is it normal practice to send an array of objects? Like the following:

```
{
    cost: 30.0,
    foods: [
        {
            id: 23,
            name: "Chicken Parmesan",
            price: 10.0
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Scotch Fillet Steak",
            price: 10.0
        },
        {
            id: 14,
            name: "Baramundi",
            price: 10.0
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sending IDs is perfectly fine, though you want to check that assigned ID are legit.

If you don't have an IDs yet and you want to create objects (or update!) through association – sending a nested array with objects is the way to go.

Also, forgot to mention!
If you are sending **just** ids – it means you are sending a "special" rails field – `food_ids`, and Rails do the magic. That's just an update of a field, that's true REST.

I'd go with `food_ids` if I have no need in changing or creating foods, and I'd go with `foods_attributes` (nested attributes) if I'd need to.

Comment: Interesting, so sending `food_ids: [23, 1,14]` will result in Rails updating an existing bill instance in the DB and associate the matching food item to the bill without the developer needing to manually write code to loop through and assign the items. That's new to me :D

Comment: Exactly! But generally I highly recommend to have a validation inside the model which assures that all assigned ids are valid. (or just foreign key in the database should be fine if there's no "special" food exists, which can not be assigned to a bill)

Comment: Additional important tip I learned the hard way - when sending your array of objects, DO NOT INCLUDE the child entity's id, only send the other attributes of the child entity. Otherwise, Rails thinks you're trying to update an existing parent entity, using the id of the child entity but fails to do so because you never specify the parent entity's id. Cyclic deference...don't know what it's called exactly :D